# Can't read .CHM file in specific folder

Tags: windows-7, chm

I have installed WiX# on my Windows 7 (64 bit) operation system. I chose the folder name C:\Users...\WiX#\ for all files. Unfortunately I can't open the .CHM file. I get an error message

> This program cannot display the
>   webpage.

I can fix this by moving the file to another place or renaming the folder WiX# to WixSharp. Why does this happen and can I display the file without renaming the folder somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [a known bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319247):

> [...] If the CHM file name contains the #
>   symbol, then the topics in the table
>   of contents do not appear. **If the path
>   contains the # symbol, then you may
>   receive an access violation error
>   message.**

The only resolution listed:

> To work around this issue, remove the #
>   symbol from the file name or from the path to the file.

The article is quite old so does not mention Windows 7 but I just tried it myself on Windows 7 Professional (32 bit) and can confirm the behaviour.

The CHM format is actually [compiled HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help). The `#` character signifies an anchor in HTML so probably the CHM viewer fails to resolve the path properly and to retrieve the content.