# How to Unblock Previously Unblocked CHM File

Tags: windows-7, chm

Wierd? Anyway, on Windows 7, I've downloaded a CHM file on the desktop and unblocked it by `Property > Unblock`.

I moved the CHM file to a folder on the desktop to organize the files, and when I opened the file, the content of the CHM reader couldn't open the pages in the CHM file. I've open the file property, but the unblocked button is gone. Well, I can simply download the file, though I find the problem interesting and I need to know how to troubleshoot it.

So, how can I unblock the said file?

**Update**
Clarified location. I was referring to a folder in the desktop, not in network drive.

Comment: "Then I moved the CHM file to another location and" Is the other location on a network drive or another remote place?

Comment: What is the name of the new folder? **Related:** http://superuser.com/questions/427191/chm-files-wont-open-in-a-certain-folder

Comment: LOL! I've placed my chm file in `desktop/MS/C#` and it appears that the `#` sign affected the access of the file. I renamed the folder to `CSharp` and the issue was resolved. Thanks, @iglvzx

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound No problem! As mentioned in my answer, the CHM tool hasn't been updated since 2002, so there are unfixed bugs like this one. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't read .CHM file in specific folder](http://superuser.com/questions/280354/cant-read-chm-file-in-specific-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not on a local drive? If so, you can allow the viewer to show chm files on a network drive:

1. Start -> Run -> Regedit
2. Search key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x`
3. Create subkey `ItssRestrictions`
4. Create DWORD `MaxAllowedZone` with value 2

This should fix it.

You may find this useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892675/en
There is a table which shows the zone levels.

Comment: Worked, but i had already added the drive letter to the intranet zone and lowered the security level.  Further i had already run `icacls P:\APPS /SetIntegrityLevel (OI)(CI)M`   Adding same parameters for just the user HKCU fails.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it through powershell

1. Start a powershell prompt
2. write "unblock-file ", do not press enter
3. Drag the file from explorer to the powershell prompt (to get the filename)
4. Hit enter.

the file should now be unblocked.